# Cache tags for all entities of a certain type

Tags: 8, caching

I understand how you can add cache tags to a custom query for a particular entity id (or list of them) but is there a way to add cache tags that will invalidate a query if any entity of type FOO is updated/added/deleted?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2145751 for the core issue to add it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the module [handy_cache_tags](https://www.drupal.org/project/handy_cache_tags), then you would have this type of tags:

```
handy_cache_tags:[entity_type]
handy_cache_tags:[entity_type]:[entity_bundle]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your blockcache_examples.module file:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
  * Invalidate the custom tag if entities of type "page" get updated
  */
function blockcache_examples_node_update(Node $entity) {
  if($entity->getType() === 'page') {
    Cache::invalidateTags(['blockcache_examples_page_updates']);
  }
}

/**
  * Invalidate the custom tag if entities of type "page" get inserted
  */
function blockcache_examples_node_insert(Node $entity) {
  if($entity->getType() === 'page') {
    Cache::invalidateTags(['blockcache_examples_page_updates']);
  }
}

/**
  * Invalidate the custom tag if entities of type "page" get deleted
  */
function blockcache_examples_node_delete(Node $entity) {
  if($entity->getType() === 'page') {
    Cache::invalidateTags(['blockcache_examples_page_updates']);
  }
}
```

In your **src/Plugin/Block/MyBlock.php** (or controller, whatever):

```php
/**
 * Only when node(s) of type 'page' are updated/insert/deleted. See .module file
 */
public function getCacheTags() {
  return Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), array('blockcache_examples_page_updates'));
}
```

Source: [this video explaining block caching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaQa4q8omQw&feature=youtu.be)